# How do I add the "viridis" colour scheme to my social network graph?

Tags: ggplot2, colors, gradient, igraph, figure

I would like to demonstrate the gradient in my points better and I believe I can do so using the "viridis" colour-scheme. At the moment I am just using steelblue and orange to demonstrate my gradient, however the mid-colour isn't very clear and comes out sort of grey.

This is the code:

```
G1.v_sub_plot <- ggraph(G1.v_sub, layout = Layout) + 
                geom_edge_link(alpha=0.2) + 
                geom_node_point(aes(colour = average_duration, 
                                    size=as.numeric(Bridge_betw),
                                    shape=as.factor(community))) +
                scale_size_continuous(range = c(5, 20)) + 
                scale_color_gradient(low="steelblue", high="orange") +
                theme_graph(base_family = 'Helvetica') +
                theme(legend.text = element_text(size=22),
                      legend.title = element_text(size=22)) +
                labs(color="Average vigilance duration", 
                     size="Bridge betweenness", 
                     shape="Community") + set.seed(123)
```

The colour demonstrates the average_duration of vigilance each individual in the network exhibits across a set period of time.

I can find how to do this on other graphs, just not a social network graph. I am open to other colours and to using breaks, I would just like the intermediate points to show up better.

I can attach the graph if that would help :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a graph that has the node attributes from your example

```r
library(igraph)

set.seed(1337)

nodes <- 
  data.frame(
    id = 1:10,
    average_duration = sample(1:20, 10),
    Bridge_betw = rnorm(10),
    community = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
  )

edges <- 
  data.frame(
    from = sample(1:10, 45, replace = TRUE),
    to = sample(1:10, 45, replace = TRUE)
  )

G1.v_sub <- 
  graph_from_data_frame(edges, TRUE, nodes)
```

You can use `scale_color_viridis()` to use the viridis palette.

```r
library(ggraph)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

ggraph(G1.v_sub) + 
  geom_edge_link(alpha=0.2) + 
  geom_node_point(aes(colour = average_duration, 
                      size=as.numeric(Bridge_betw),
                      shape=as.factor(community))) +
  #scale_size_continuous(range = c(5, 20)) + 
  scale_color_viridis() +
  theme_graph(base_family = 'Helvetica') +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size=22),
        legend.title = element_text(size=22)) +
  labs(color="Average vigilance duration", 
       size="Bridge betweenness", 
       shape="Community")
#> Using "stress" as default layout
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>